# MongoDB Aggregation query running very slow

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, document-versioning

We version most of our collections in Mongodb. The selected versioning mechanism is as follows:

```
{  "docId" : 174, "v" : 1,  "attr1": 165 }   /*version 1 */
{  "docId" : 174, "v" : 2,  "attr1": 165, "attr2": "A-1" } 
{  "docId" : 174, "v" : 3,  "attr1": 184, "attr2" : "A-1" }
```

So, when we perform our queries we always need to use the aggregation framework in this way to ensure get latest versions of our objects:

```
db.docs.aggregate( [  
    {"$sort":{"docId":-1,"v":-1}},
    {"$group":{"_id":"$docId","doc":{"$first":"$$ROOT"}}}
    {"$match":{<query>}}
] );
```

The problem with this approach is once you have done your grouping, you have a set of data in memory which has nothing to do with your collection and thus, your indexes cannot be used.

As a result, the more documents your collection has, the slower the query gets.

Is there any way to speed this up?

If not, I will consider to move to one of the approaches defined in this good post: http://www.askasya.com/post/trackversions/

Comment: why you haven't $match at first stage?

Comment: Add a index to docId field of your document.

Comment: @DanieleTassone I am afraid that is not an option. Explanation is in link I provided. Basically, if you filter at the beginning, you will end up with versions which are not the latest but the sort-group phase will consider them as such. It is a common error when performing versioning like this.

Comment: @Parshuram Adding an index to docId would speed up the group operation but not the following $match, wouldn't it?

Comment: @jbernal i saw the Link with the details. The most efficient way is explained in the link (db.docs.find({"docId":174}).sort({"v":-1}).limit(-1);) where you can exactly what you want. This work fine if you need 1 document. If you need more documents at same time is a different story: this is something i have not understand, can you explain it better? There are different solutions, but i should understand better. Also - can we consider MongoDB 3.4?

Comment: @DanieleTassone I was meaning the case for retrieving several documents. Imagine you want to perform a normal query to find documents which match a particular field. Then you need to perform the aforementioned aggregate operation which gets really slow as the number of documents increases. I am considering to move to choice 3 explained in the link which is also revisited in follow-up post. MongoDB 3.4 is not an option I am afraid.

Comment: @jbernal ok then can you tell me the MongoDB version you can use?

Comment: @DanieleTassone Sure, MongoDB 3.2 but not still in WiredTiger. We are planning to upgrade shortly and get some benefit from the performance improvement.

Comment: @jbernal Ok i will think about. I understood now the point related the $match clausole at the top; it's right you cant' until you are only looking for specific _id. If you are making "complex query" you can't. So the question is what you are making in this $match? Just query-by-ids should be fine.

Comment: @DanieleTassone not always. I might want to find documents whose name is certain string. For this reason, I want to be able to filter by any field in $match. I´ve done some research and I don´t think it is possible. I will move to third choice I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in order to complete this question, we went with option 3: one collection to keep latest versions and one collection to keep historical ones. It is introduced here: http://www.askasya.com/post/trackversions/ and some further description (with some nice code snippets) can be found in http://www.askasya.com/post/revisitversions/.

It has been running in production now for 6 months. So far so good. Former approach meant we were always using the aggregate framework which moves away from indexes as soon as you modify the original schema (using $group, $project...) as it doesn't match anymore the original collection. This was making our performance terrible as the data was growing.

With the new approach though the problem is gone. 90% of our queries goes against latest data and this means we target a collection with a simple `ObjectId` as identifier and we do not require aggregate framework anymore, just regular finds.

Our queries against historical data always include `id` and `version` so by indexing these (we include both as `_id` so we get it out of the box), reads towards those collections are equally fast. This is a point though not to overlook. Read patterns in your application are crucial when designing how your collections/schemas should look like in MongoDB so you must ensure you know them when taking such decisions.